# Coding a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I need to create a sequence of number `a_t` according to a old sequence of number `z_t` and `a_0`. `a_t` is define equal to `27 if t=0` or `a(t-1)exp(z(t-1)) for t>=1`. I am not even sure how to write this is python. Here is a try

```
i=0
a_t=[]
a_0=27
z_t = pred_values
for x in pred_values:
   a_t.append(a_0*exp(x))
   i+=1
```

Is that a proper way to code that recursive function?

**Update 1**

I messed up in the code. Once we use `a_0`, we need to use a_t. For instance, if I want to use `a_2`, then clearly we will need to use `a_1`. Is there a proper way to code that function?

**Update 2**

It seems possible to work with `a_0` only and the sum over `z_t-1, z_t-2, ..., z0` instead of waiting for `a_t-1` to compute `a_t`. So it is possible to vectorize the computation instead of computing the `a_i` one after the other. Are you up to give me the following option with `numpy`, i.e. `a_t = a_0 exp(sum(z_i))` for `i=0 to t-1`? It is probably faster to compute as we already know the sequence `z_t`.

Comment: Why do you want to do that recursively in the first place?

Comment: That is not recursive. https://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php

Comment: Are you sure that's the right definition? With `a_0 == 0`, you can use induction to prove that `a_t == 0` for all `t >= 0`.

Comment: `a_0=Xtrue[:, :, -1][0][i]`. It was an error to say `a_0` is set to `0` because it is wrong. Let's assume `a_0` is set to `27` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way to define such a sequence is with a generator.

```
import math

def a_t(zs, a=27):
    z = next(zs)
    yield a
    for z in zs:
        a *= math.exp(z)
        yield a

a_t = list(a_t(pred_values))
```

Comment: a_0 is set to 27. It was a big mistake to set it to zero. Can you fix your code?

Comment: Done. Note that I've made the generator more general by letting you pass the desired starting value as an argument.